# How will ADA Boost be used for solving regression problems?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, bigdata, regression

I have an idea of how ADABOOST will be used for classification but I want to get the idea of how to re-weight and thus use ADABOOST in case of regression problems.

Answer (score 5):

Here are link to some famous boost of regressor.

- [Adaboost.R2: Improving Regressors using Boosting Techniques](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.31.314&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [Adaboost.RT: Experiments with AdaBoost.RT, an Improved Boosting
  Scheme for Regression](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.4560&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Scikit-Learn have many implementations:

- [AdaBoostRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostRegressor.html)
- [Decision Tree Regression with AdaBoost](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_adaboost_regression.html)

Answer (score 0):

AdaBoost is a meta algorithm, so the underlying principle is the same: i would suggest going through [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#adaboost) for references.

Answer (score 0):

As a general principle Adaboost builds and ensemble by sequentially adding members which have been trained on those instances of data which are proving most difficult to correctly classify/predict.

Each new classifier/predictor is given a training set where the difficult examples are increasingly represented, this is achieved either through weighting or resampling.

There should be very little difference in the approach for classification or regression.